# sass plugin in play!framework 2.0.4 throws error

Tags: ruby, playframework-2.0, sass, jruby

We've been using play!framework 2.0.4 for a year now, with `SASS`.

We got a new project member and he is getting a really strange error from sass.

```
Sass compiler: ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- d:/workspace/our-project/sass (LoadError)
```

The computer is running Windows 7.

I can tell you we had problems with ruby as well.

For some reason `irb` command failed. But we fixed it by changing the value of `HOME` environment variable from `%USERPROFILE%` to `c:\Users\name`

I've seen this problem in google groups too, but without a solution

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/j1npLLQlj1o/POOlePhJv1QJ

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I've never been much of a fan of patches or work-arounds so I'll try my best to analyze what is going on here:

The play framework is of little interest here based on the error message you've highlighted in your posts above so we'll start there.

We have ruby being called by the sass compiler that is complaining about a load error.  Fair enough.  At first glance, one would presume to think a ruby configuration is to blame because of the ruby.exe error message.  However, we find that it is indeed looking for a file, namely, sass.bat, so my curious eyes take me there.

Consequently, we find that the batch file contains the following:

```
1   @ECHO OFF
2   IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
3   @"ruby.exe" "C:/Ruby193/bin/sass" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
4   GOTO :EOF
5   :WinNT
6   @"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

So there is 6 command lines in this script, not too bad.  By inspection, I notice line 2 has an if condition that relies upon taking all the parameters of what is being executed or the full name.  The condition seems to evaluate as false when testing on Windows 7 so we always end up on line 6.  The key to this problem is the machine running Ruby on Windows.

Essentially, we have a "jump subroutine" or GOTO instruction to hit WinNT in the script, so we are looking for sass.bat in the current directory, yielding your current error.

Here's the skinny:  you can comment the if condition in line 2 of the sass.bat file by doing

```
REM IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
```

or you can make line 6 identical to line 3.  After making the modification, your sass compiler will know where to find Ruby SASS.

I like windows, but this isn't a problem on OS X as Ruby is preinstalled.  Some people have attempted to create aliases for ruby/sass but the source of the problem is not the PATH environment variable.

In my example, Ruby is installed on C: using version 1.93 but the same applies for all recent versions including v2.

I hope this helps!

Comment: superb answer , I have spent lot of time in solving this than finally this solution works

Answer (score 0):

For all of you who run into this issue and need a working work-around, here is what we found

The error `Sass compiler: ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- d:/workspace/our-project/sass (LoadError)` means that ruby is looking for a **file** (not a folder) named `sass` in the project root directory. The reason for that is unclear and still requires explanation if anyone can contribute.

This `sass` file is a ruby file, the same file that should exist at `c:\Ruby187\bin\sass` which is basically the sass plugin ruby code.

So a quick work around to fix this would be to **copy** that file under your root directory.

This resolved it for us.

I still need an explanation as to why this happens in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to work for play 2.3.x using litola sass-plugin 0.4.0. If I place the sass directory in my project. The output css files under target/scala-2.11/classes/public/xxx are all 0 sized.
Any suggestions? Still investigating.

Solution has been reached that does not require copying the sass windows scripts into workspace.
This plugin works: https://github.com/ShaggyYeti/sbt-sass under play 2.3.x.
QED